# response.data/ response.d displayed "undefined"

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to retrieve a list from C# code to an `aspx` page using ajax.

this is the ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'admin.aspx/getGenderCount',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: '{}',
    success: successRetireveGenders,
    failure: function (response) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});

function successRetireveGenders(dataValues) {
    alert(dataValues); // displayed [object object]
    // but i actually have 2 rows result

    alert(dataValues.data);       //alert with "undefined"
    alert(dataValues.d);          //alert with "undefined"

    // i try to put loop from 0 to response.d.length
    for (var i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
               alert(dataValues.length);   //alert with "undefined"
               alert(dataValues.d.length);  //alert with "undefined"
}
```

I am always seeing an alert with message:

> undefined

c# code:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<ParticipantGender> getGenderCount()
    {
        List<ParticipantGender> ListOfParticipantGender = new List<ParticipantGender>();
        var conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

            cmd = new SqlCommand("getGenderCount", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (rdr.HasRows)
                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    ListOfParticipantGender.Add(
                     new ParticipantGender
                     {
                         cnt = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                         gender = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString(),

                     });
                }



        return ListOfParticipantGender;
    }
```

ParticipantGender class:

```
public class ParticipantGender
{
    public string gender;
    public string cnt;



    public ParticipantGender()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }

    public ParticipantGender(string gender, string cnt)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
        this.cnt = cnt;

    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'admin.aspx/getGenderCount',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '{}',
                success: callback,
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

var callback = function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert("hi");    // not alerted
            alert(data + "\t" + textStatus);    // not alerted
        };
```

EDIT:
i got in the console:

> jsapi:23 A parser-blocking, cross site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart,
>   is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY
>   be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor
>   network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be
>   confirmed in a subsequent console message. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details. google.loader.f @ jsapi:23 jsapi:23 A parser-blocking, cross
>   site (i.e. different eTLD+1) script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/40ff64b1d9d6b3213524485974f36cc0/format+en,default+en,ui+en,corechart+en.I.js,
>   is invoked via document.write. The network request for this script MAY
>   be blocked by the browser in this or a future page load due to poor
>   network connectivity. If blocked in this page load, it will be
>   confirmed in a subsequent console message. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5718547946799104 for more
>   details. google.loader.f @ jsapi:23 fontawesome-webfont.woff2:1 Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found)

Comment: Add `getGenderCount` code as well please

Comment: Change `alert(dataValues);` to `console.log(dataValues);` and please share what was written to the console. Additionally, please use Network tab in Chrome Developer tools to get the exact payload returned from the http request (and include that in your question).

Comment: Any luck with that @AlaaAlarfaj?

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize the `List<ParticipantGender>` to JSON. You can install package `Newtonsoft.Json` which provides a lot of features.

For your case

```
using System.Configuration;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string getGenderCount() 
{

 var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
 var ListOfParticipantGender = new List<ParticipantGender>();

 using(var conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
 {
    conn.Open();

    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("getGenderCount", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;            

        using(var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (rdr.HasRows)
            {    
                while (rdr.Read()) {

                    ListOfParticipantGender.Add(
                            new ParticipantGender 
                            {
                                cnt = rdr.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                                gender = rdr.GetValue(1).ToString(),

                            }
                       );
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }

 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ListOfParticipantGender);

 return json;
}
```

Define the `Callback` function with necessary parameters and assign it to the `$.ajax` success event.

Also, there is no such event `failure` for [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead use `error`

```
var callback = function(data, textStatus, xhr)
{
    alert(data + "\t" + textStatus);
};
```

Assign this `callback` to the success event

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'admin.aspx/getGenderCount',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {},
        success: callback,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Check my updated code. Also, check for any console errors?

Comment: return json retrieve an errr: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ParticipantGender>'

Comment: public static string getGenderCount()

Comment: Check my updated code and check if there are any errors in console in browser.

Comment: Did you checked with break points? whether the ajax call hit the getGenderCount method?

Comment: yes it all done perfectly but when it retrieved to the ajax it is undefined

Comment: Try assigning the callback within `$.ajax` itself, `success: function (data) { console.log(data) }`

Comment: shall i use success: callback or success: function(data)?

Comment: success: function (data)